# Count transaction during time interval in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
   select users.uid,
          tran.event
     from public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users users
left join public.app_ok_CBAIODCLEBABABABA_agg_transactions tran  
       on users.uid=tran.uid
    where first_event_time >= '2017-09-01 0:00:00'
      and first_event_time <= '2017-09-11 0:00:00'
      and tran.event = 'successful transaction'
```

In this query we choose user `id(uid)`, `event` (it is transaction event successful or not) and time interval from `2017-09-01 to 2017-09-11` (it's date when he registered).

So how to calculate the number of Transactions that each user made during the week?

The decision

```
add this string AND  datediff(day,first_event_time, event_time)<=7
```

thank you, dear friends

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Miscosoft SQL -server

Answer (score 1):

This is tough without seeing your data, but it looks like you're after something like this;

```
SELECT
    users.uid,
    tran.event,
    COUNT(tran.event) Event_Count
FROM public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users users
LEFT JOIN public.app_ok_CBAIODCLEBABABABA_agg_transactions tran  
    ON users.uid=tran.uid
WHERE  first_event_time >='2017-09-01 0:00:00'
    AND first_event_time <= '2017-09-11 0:00:00'
    AND tran.event='successful transaction'
GROUP BY users.uid,tran.event
```

This will count the entries in tran.event that meet your criteria in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: what to do, that i don't manually enter interval?. Sql must automatically calculate interval for users. 1.09-8.09, 2.09-9.09 and so on

Comment: I'd make a date table containing Week_Num, Start_Date, End_Date and join onto that. there's where you're going to get the best performance

Answer (score 1):

```
select  
COUNT(*),
first_event_time
from public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users users
left join public.app_ok_CBAIODCLEBABABABA_agg_transactions tran  on 
users.uid=tran.uid
where  first_event_time>='2017-09-01 0:00:00'
and first_event_time <= '2017-09-11 0:00:00'
and tran.event='successful transaction'
GROUP BY first_event_time
```

Comment: This will show you transactions per time. See answers above for grouping per user.

Comment: what to do, that i don't manually enter interval?. Sql must automatically calculate interval for users. 1.09-8.09, 2.09-9.09 and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Group by` on User ID.
Please try this:

```
select x.userId,count(*) NumberOfTransaction
(
  select  
  users.uid userId,
  tran.event tEvent
  from public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users users
  left join public.app_ok_CBAIODCLEBABABABA_agg_transactions tran  on 
  users.uid=tran.uid
  where  first_event_time>='2017-09-08 0:00:00'
  and first_event_time <= '2017-09-15 0:00:00'
  and tran.event='successful transaction'
) x
Group By x.userId
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what to do, that i don't manually enter interval?. Sql must automatically calculate interval for users. 1.09-8.09, 2.09-9.09 and so on

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select u.uid, sum(t.uid)
from public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users u left join
     public.app_ok_CBAIODCLEBABABABA_agg_transactions t
     on u.uid = t.uid and
        t.? >= '2017-09-08' and
        t.? < '2017-09-16' and
        t.event = 'successful transaction'
where first_event_time >= '2017-09-01' and
      first_event_time < '2017-09-12';
```

Your question is not clear about which column to use for the event time.

Also note that the date logic has changed.

Comment: on u.uid = t.uid and
        t.? >= '2017-09-08' and
        t.? < '2017-09-16'  . what to do, that i don't manually enter interval?. Sql must autamatically calculate interval for users. 1.09-8.09, 2.09-9.09 and so on.

Comment: @D.Joe . . . Replace the `?` with the column that has the dates you are referring to.

Comment: t.event_time, i need calculate for each users his transaction during the week after his registeration. In your solution i must manually enter the data. 01.09-08.09, and then query 02.09-09.09 and so on:))

Comment: @D.Joe . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, ask it in a question, not in a comment.

Comment: It's ok   AND  datediff(day,first_event_time, event_time)<=7 , i just add this string to your query, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can try like bellow

select
u.uid,
tn.event
from users u
left join transactions tn  on 
u.uid=tn.uid
where tran.event='successful transaction' and  first_event_time between '2017-09-01 0:00:00' and '2017-09-11 0:00:00'